# Lengthen side edges of node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Say I have a simple rectangular node I wish to lengthen some sides of, such that they extend further from the corners. Simple, here is my attempt:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (x) {foo};
    \draw (x.north west) -- ++(0, +1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Result of MWE]

I see what the problem is: `x.north west` is exactly at the corner of the shape and `draw` draws the line from this corner in such a way that the drawn path protrudes by `pgflinewidth/2` in both directions along the trajectory I specified (if that makes sense; sorry, it is rather hard to explain).

**My question is, how do I draw the line so that it looks like it extends the original side of the `x` node?**

- I suppose the `x.north east` anchor is where it is, there is no other anchor that just happens to be where I need it
- One thing I thought of is making the `draw` command `\draw[xshift=.5\pgflinewidth]`, but it did not cause any change and feels a bit hacky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,outer sep=0pt] (x) {foo};
    \draw (x.north west) -- ++(0, +1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Anchor of nodes is on outside of node's borders, i.e. for `outer sep` moved from middle of borders lines. This you can change by settings `outside sep=0pt`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! One can confirm what is happening by adding eg `\draw[red,line width=.1pt] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(x.north west)};`, to visualize where the anchor is.

Answer (score 2):

*Improving on my attempted ‘hacky’ solution:*

As far as I understand, `xshift` does not apply to points referenced by nodes, in this case `(x.north west)`. Instead, one can use `transform canvas`, like this:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (x) {foo};
    \draw[transform canvas={xshift=.5\pgflinewidth}] (x.north west) -- ++(0, +1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Result of LaTeX code]

This ultimately solves my problem, but does not feel quite right. Is there a *better* way to do this? ☺